# Why linearlayout in constraintlayout giving error?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I am getting error in LinearLayout tag while using linearlayout in constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tourwip2.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Username: "
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password: "
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any way to resolve that?

Comment: You needs to give constraints to LinearLayot.

Comment: `ContraintLayout` is meant for flat layout structure, why do you even need a `LinearLayout` inside it? I can understand the specific use cases though for that too, but, I don't think you're handling such.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use any *layout* or view *inside* a `ConstraintLayout` you must provide constraints.

Just add these lines inside your **XML** in your `LinearLayout` tag

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

After adding your code should look like

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"                                 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide constraints to all view inside Constraint Layout, also this applies for ViewGroups like Linear Layout, and Relative Layout.
Mainly you have to provide X, Y, X-end, Y-end, width or height, any 4 from them.

These bottom simple XML additions to Linear Layout will solve your problem.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```